# БД на html без php

Tags: html, база-данных

как можно сделать регистрацию и авторизацию без php только на javascript,html,css и все?

Вот кусочек кода от регистрации

```
введите сюда код
<html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Регистрация</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="bod">
<form action="">
    <h1 id="h">Регистрация</h1>
    <div class="group"></div>
    <label for="">Имя пользователя</label>
    <input type="text" >
    <div class="group"></div>
    <label for="">Пароль</label>
    <input type="password" >
    <div class="group"></div>
    <label for="">Повторите пароль</label>
    <input type="password" >
    <div class="group"></div>
    <label for="">Адрес электронной почты</label>
    <input type="email" >
    <div class="group"></div>
    <center><button id="b1">Зарегистрироваться</button></center>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я не спец в этом, но думаю, для этого вам потребуется умение программировать на `node.js`

Comment: Без серверной части и серверного языка, например php, node.js, java, python это нельзя сделать.

Comment: Ну если только например localstorage на стороне клиента использовать.

Comment: Вы готовы показать клиенту логин, пароль и адрес SQL сервера?  javascript,html,css - это все отправляется в браузер клиента и доступно ему для просмотра.